# PHP JSON UTF-8 cant handle polish characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, utf-8

I want to write little script returning JSON from all news table in my database. The problem is that json_encode() cant correctly encode polish characters.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$sql="SELECT * FROM news";
$q = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {

    $row['news_content'] = utf8_encode($row['news_content']);
    $row['news_title'] = utf8_encode($row['news_title']);

    $tab[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
$result = json_encode($tab);
echo $result;
?>
```

When I get from database text with 'ł' character json encodes it into \u00b3 which is "superscript three"

My whole database and tables are set to UTF-8.

Strange (for me) thing is, when I use

```
$row['news_content'] = utf8_encode($row['news_content']);
```

then

```
echo utf8_decode($row['news_content']);
```

it shows correctly the 'ł' character, but when i decode my json output, it doesnt work..

Comment: Is your *connection* also set to UTF-8?

Comment: I see you're using `json_encode()`. UTF-8 can handle Polish characters. ISO-8859-1 cannot!

Comment: BTW, I'm a great fan of Stanisław Lem :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)